# Hide HTML element depending on page text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to hide a div with javascript but only on the condition that certain text appears in a separate element within the DOM.

For example if the word 'arthritis or Testosterone' appears in the h1 element on the page (below) THEN hide element 'x' otherwise keep it visible.

```
<h1>Arthritis</h1>

<div class="x">
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this with Javascript. What did you try to achieve your goal? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since is a H1 title, I presume that appears only one time, right? So, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ( $("#the_title:contains(arthritis)") || $("#the_title:contains(testosterone)") ) {
    $(".x").css("background-color", "yellow");
      //$(".x").hide(); uncomment this to hide the element
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="the_title">Arthritis</h1>

<div class="x">
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const element = [...document.querySelectorAll("h1")]
 .find( el => el.innerHTML === 'Arthritis' || el.innerHTML === 'Testosterone');
if(element !=undefined && element !=null)
{
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('x');

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
      x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
console.log(element);
```

```html
<h1>Arthritis</h1>

<div class="x">
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
var c=document.getElementsByClassName('one')[0];
var t=document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
if(t.innerText.toLowerCase()==="arthritis"||t.innerText.toLowerCase()==="testosterone")
{c.style.display = "none";}
else
 c.style.display="block";
```